# python code to convert json data to cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

am new to cassandra 
i have a json file with the below content. i need store these information in cassandra db

Thanks in advance

```
{
    "languages": {
        "python": "Elite", 
        "pascal": "Lame",             <dictionary in list>
        "perl": "Elite"
    }, 
    "foods": [
        "Apple", 
        "Orange",                     <list in dictionary>
        "Strawberry", 
        "Mango"
    ], 
    "name": "Martin D'vloper",         <dictionary>
    "employed": "true", 
    "skill": "Elite", 
    "job": "Developer"
}
```

Comment: what is your target table structure?

Comment: Alex Ott -  as of now no idea on on table structure, but am trying for the below format. [correct me if am wrong]
 name      | record
-----------+--------------------------------------------
 languages | {'pascal': 'Lame', 'perl': 'Elite', 'python': 'Elite'}
 foods     | ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Mango']
 name    | Martin D'vloper
 employed  | true
 skill     | Elite
 job       | Developer

Comment: Also if possible direct me how to store the above json in cassandra

Comment: table structure depends on how you'll query the data, do you know what queries will be executed?